# How do you destructure values in a let binding using algebraic racket

Tags: racket, algebraic-data-types

I'm trying to work through the tutorial on delimited continuations here [http://pllab.is.ocha.ac.jp/~asai/cw2011tutorial/main-e.pdf](http://pllab.is.ocha.ac.jp/%7Easai/cw2011tutorial/main-e.pdf) using Racket instead of OCaml, but hitting snags when trying to express my program using Racket's algebraic data types so that my example code tracks closely to the tutorial.

Specifically, I cannot figure out how to bind the fields of an instance using a `let` form. In this simple example, I define a `Tree` sum type with two product types `Empty` and `Node` where each node will contain a left branch, a value, and a right branch.

```lisp
#lang algebraic/racket/base
(require algebraic/function)

(data Tree (Empty Node))

(define tree1 (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty)))

(let ([(Node left value right) tree1]) value)
```

What I'd expect is that this expression would evaluate to `2` because `value` is bound to the value field of the root node, but instead it fails with `let: bad syntax (not an identifier) in: (Node left value right)`. However if I understand [the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/algebraic/ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._algebraic%2Fracket%2Fbase%2Fforms..rkt%29._let%29%29) correctly, this is something that ought to be possible.

For example, I'm able to define the `walk` function to recursively visit each node in the tree and use pattern matching to bind the left and right sides of the tree and this works just great.

```lisp
(define walk (function
 [Empty `done]
 [(Node left value right)
  (walk left)
  (println value)
  (walk right)]))
```

I just can't seem to do it in the context of `let`. Is my syntax wrong? Am I using the right version of `let`? Is this something you can even do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `algebraic/racket/base` doesn't provide the syntax for `let`, and so its just getting it from vanilla `racket/base`. Not sure if that's intentional or a bug, but either way you can work around it by adding `(require algebraic/racket/base/forms)` to your code. Giving you:

```
#lang algebraic/racket/base

(require algebraic/racket/base/forms)
(require algebraic/function)

(data Tree (Empty Node))

(define tree1 (Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty)))

(let ([(Node left value right) tree1]) value)
```

Which evaluates to `2`.